# When getting data using HTML AGILITY PACK in C# sometimes the app gets data?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have been getting some data using the HTML AGILITY PACK to get data from a webpage by selecting some tags, but I have a bug or something.   Sometimes the web page times out and the app doesn't get data.  How should I get rid of this because I need to refresh the page again and again?

Here's my  code:

```
string Url = "http://gmail.com";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
var SpanNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='form-field wide-80 
normal']");
```

How can I refresh the web page in the browser using C# or how can I get data using HTML AGILITY PACK by opening a web page in a web browser? ....please guide me in how to do this.

Comment: it rather depends on your connectivity to the target site I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

HTML AGILITY PACK is good at parsing data from a webpage, if you want to automate/control (e.g. navigate, refresh etc.) a webpage, consider using [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

```
IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);   
driver.Navigate().Refresh();      // <--- here it gets refreshed
```

BTW: your frequent refresh/crawl data from an url, it is in most cases infeasible, and as your traffic grows, most web site will prompte you to enter CAPTCHA, and it will be a hard time for you to further grab data therein. This though might be off topic, :)

Answer (score 0):

Building a so-called scraper and refreshing a webpage very frequently might cause a temporary ban to avoid burdening the server(s) too much.